# End Date must follow Start Date on cart price schdule new update

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, schedule

Does anyone experience this before, am trying to add schedule update for my rule in admin when I tried to save am getting End Date must follow Start Date

Error comes from vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/AbstractModel.php

I tried to print the start date and end date, getting some weird data

> [2019-07-17 13:32:17] report.INFO: foo
>   {"fromdate":"2016-10-19","to":"2019-03-31"} [] [2019-07-17 13:32:17]
>   report.INFO: foo {"fromdate":"2019-07-17","to":"2019-03-31"} []

Datepicker posting wrong values 
[image]

am using Magento 2.3.2 Enterprise

Comment: This is timezone issue. Which timezone did you use?

Comment: @SohelRana m using CEST +0200

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue. In may case error was in var/log/exception.

```
[2021-08-05 05:20:57] report.CRITICAL: End Date must follow Start Date.;  {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): End Date must follow Start Date.;  at /app/xxxxxxx/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Converter/ToModel.php:197)"} []
```

The reason of this issue was in table salesrule. As you can see in the picture

[image]

In the second row you can see from_date is lesser than to_date. So you need to fix the from_date.

I hope it will help you or anyone who is facing this issue.

Second solution: If you do not want to delete your records then change the from_date and to_date according to created_in and updated_in timestamps dates.